# Go parse JSON with 2 nested types

Tags: json, go, struct, interface

I have 2 objects, for example:

```
type appA struct {
  appType string
  frontend string
}

type appB struct {
  appType string
  backend string
}
```

I have a configuration file in JSON format, for example:

```
[
  {
    "appType" : "A",
    "frontend": "URL"
  },
  {
    "appType": "B",
    "backend": "SQL"
  }
]
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47911187/golang-elegantly-json-decode-different-structures) great idea - I've created another struct:

```
type genericApp struct {
  appType string
}
```

So now I can unmarshal the JSON nicely and know which object in the JSON is which kind of app. Now my big issue is how to "marshal & unmarshall" again - can I reference the already unmarshalled objects as interface somehow and re-unmarshal them as different objects?

The only other solution I have is to read the file N times, each for every struct type, and then loop through the genericApp array and "gather" the matching object from the relevant array, but that sounds like an awful practice...

**EDIT**
I've answered the question using the `json:...omitempty` notation, but I still have an issue - what if two separate objects have the same field name with different types? e.g. appType could be string or number?

Comment: Firstly, you should export your struct fields for json unmarshaling, probably you didn't pay attention but it is important for new comers to see a correct question.

Answer (score 2):

create a config.json file an put that json inside and then try id :

```
type MyAppModel struct {
    AppType  string `json:"appType"`
    Frontend string `json:"frontend,omitempty"`
    Backend  string `json:"backend,omitempty"`
}

func(m *MyAppModel) GetJson()string{
    bytes,_:=json.Marshal(m)
    return string(bytes)
}

func (m MyAppModel) GetListJson(input []MyAppModel) string {
    bytes,_:=json.Marshal(input)
    return string(bytes)
}

func(m MyAppModel) ParseJson(inputJson string)[]MyAppModel{
    model:=[]MyAppModel{}
    err:=json.Unmarshal([]byte(inputJson),&model)
    if err!=nil{
        println(err.Error())
        return nil
    }
    return model
}

func inSomeMethodLikemain(){
    //reading from file
    bytes,err:=ioutil.ReadFile("config.json")
    if err!=nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    configs := MyAppModel{}.ParseJson(string(bytes))
    if configs==nil || len(configs)==0{
        panic(errors.New("no config data in config.json"))
    }
    println(configs[0].AppType)

    //writing to file

    jsonOfList:=MyAppModel{}.GetListJson(configs)
    err=ioutil.WriteFile("config.json",[]byte(jsonOfList),os.ModePerm))
    if err!=nil{
        panic(err.Error())
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Found out that you can use some go syntax to create a large struct:

```
type genericApp struct {
  appType string
  frontend string `json:"frontend, omitempty"`
  backend string `json:"backend, omitempty"`
}
```

However, this has some issues:

1. It's going to create a huge struct if you have many types (if I had 20 app types instead of 2, this would be 100 lines long)
2. It doesn't give you two separate structs - you still need to implement this separation later (switch-case, or type casting etc.)